# How to create custom NIntegrate with special option behavior?

Tags: numerical-integration, options, customization, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a custom version of `NIntegrate`, called `MyNIntegrate`, with custom option behavior. In particular, I'd like the following criteria to be met:

- Default values for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are both `10`.
- Unless `WorkingPrecision` is set explicitly when calling `MyNIntegrate`, this option automatically takes the value of three times the maximum of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`.
- Any of the standard options for `NIntegrate` can be fed into `MyNIntegrate` explicitly, and are then passed along to `NIntegrate`.

I've tried implementing this with the standard `Options` tools, but I don't really know what `opts:OptionsPattern[]` and `OptionValue` are doing under the hood, so I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to do what you want. (You might wanna remove the `Print` line at some point.)

```
Clear[MyNIntegrate];
Options[MyNIntegrate] = Options[NIntegrate];
MyNIntegrate[int_, args___] :=
  Block[{ranges, opts},
   opts = Cases[{args}, _Rule];
   ranges = Complement[{args}, opts];
   
   If[FreeQ[opts, AccuracyGoal -> _], opts = Append[opts, AccuracyGoal -> 10]];
   If[FreeQ[opts, PrecisionGoal -> _], opts = Append[opts, PrecisionGoal -> 10]];
   
   If[FreeQ[opts, WorkingPrecision -> _],
    opts = 
     Append[opts, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 3*Max[AccuracyGoal /. opts, PrecisionGoal /. opts]]
    ];

   Print[opts];

   NIntegrate[int, Evaluate[Sequence @@ ranges], Evaluate[opts]]
  ];
```

```
MyNIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]

(*During evaluation of In[173]:= {PrecisionGoal->20,Method->{GlobalAdaptive,Method->ClenshawCurtisRule},MaxRecursion->20,AccuracyGoal->10,WorkingPrecision->60}*)

(* 1.10456949966230204653590120649568830997449857498155244452310 *)
```

````
MyNIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"}, 
 MinRecursion -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 20]

(* During evaluation of In[175]:= {PrecisionGoal->12,WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision,Method->{GlobalAdaptive,Method->ClenshawCurtisRule},MinRecursion->3,MaxRecursion->20,AccuracyGoal->10} *)

(* 1.10457 *)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.

Comment: Can you explain why the `Evaluate` is necessary in the `Evaluate[opts]`? I noticed that it doesn't work without this, but I don't understand why.

Comment: "Can you explain why the Evaluate is necessary[...]" -- `NIntegrate` has the attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: But why does `opts` need to be evaluated? It is just a list of options.

Comment: "But why does `opts` need to be evaluated? It is just a list of options." -- Because `NIntegrate` has the attribute `HoldAll` without `Evaluate` `NIntegrate` "sees" a symbol `opts`, not a list of options.