# How to manually create options that can be entered as a sequence or list?

Tags: options, optional-arguments

I am trying to implement custom options in my code manually, rather than using the built-in `Options` tools. So I have functions that look like `f[x_,y_,opts___]` where `opts` is intended to be a (possibly empty) list or sequence of rules.

I'd like to be able to enter `opts` as a sequence or list, but I'm having a very hard time getting my code to cover both cases. How can I program my functions so that `opts` is converted to a list of rules, regardless of whether they are fed into the function as a list or sequence?

Comment: Make it a list then `Flatten` in case it already was a list, i.e., `options = {opts} // Flatten`

Comment: I think this will ruin any options that take lists as values. I.e., suppose I have an option like `Range->{0,10}`. Won't `Flatten` ruin this?

Comment: Actually it didn't—I guess I just don't understand `Flatten`

Comment: @WillG those rules would still remain in some `Rule[a,b]` `FullForm`.

Comment: "trying to implement custom options in my code manually, rather than using the built-in Options tools" - don't. It is a very rare occurrence when you really justifiably need to re-invent the wheel, unless it's for educational purposes. If you think you need a functionality that `Options` & Co don't cover, then perhaps ask a question about that. I always worry that these questions might stem from an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MarcoB I did in fact ask a question about how to achieve a certain goal with `Options`, and the recommendation was to implement something like what I'm discussing here. See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234480/how-to-create-custom-nintegrate-with-special-option-behavior

Comment: @WillG Anton's answer to the question you linked definitely uses the existing `Options` machinery though, not a custom-made system. What am I missing?

Comment: @MarcoB Does it? I figured that since `args___` does not use `:OptionsPattern[]`, it was really more of a technique that mimicked the `Options` functionality without actually using it. The answer includes a line `Options[MyNIntegrate] = Options[NIntegrate];` but I'm pretty sure this was unnecessary. So I just figured why use `Options` at all—it seemed to just add the needless requirement of setting `Options` for each of my custom functions without actually offering benefits.

Comment: But for all I know, it may indeed have been simpler to continue using `Options`.

Answer (score 3):

[`OptionsPattern[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html) does allow entering `opts` ***as a sequence or list***:

> [image]

***Examples:***

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[Sin[x t], {t, 0, Pi}, opts]

Row[{f[5, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
  f[5, {PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300}], 
  f[5, PlotStyle -> Red, {Frame -> True}, {{{ImageSize -> 300}}}]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Framed @ Style[x, opts]

Row[{f2["ABC",
     FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 62, FontFamily -> "French Script MT"], 
 f2["ABC", 
    {FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 62, FontFamily -> "French Script MT"}], 
 f2["ABC", 
    FontColor -> Red, {{{FontSize -> 62, {{{{ FontFamily -> "French Script MT"}}}}}}}]},
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]